# Outlook for other users

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, setup

I take care of some of the minor IT applications. One of which is setting up users outlook. I'm question is there a way to set up a user's email account in Outlook without logging in as the user? We do not use Microsoft exchange server for our email applications

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. However, it generally involves the use of Microsoft's (or 3rd party) enterprise deployment tools.

It *may* be possible to achieve this using the free "[PowerShell Outlook Account Manager](http://psoutlookmanager.codeplex.com/)" however, it is listed only as supporting Outlook 2003 & 2007.

There is also the Office Customization Tool which pre-configures Office so is not quite what you are asking for.

You could also set something up yourself by working out the required entries in users registries and putting a script around that to customise for each user.

Then there is the [Outlook Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062%28office.14%29.aspx) file that you might use again to pre-configure outlook profile creation for users.